# Rotate plotted points of an ellipse to give a circle

Tags: r, matrix, plot, trigonometry

I have an ellipse-shaped distribution that I think is a conic section. I want to rotate the points so that the distribution becomes circular-shaped, as if I was looking at the conic section directly over the top of the cone.

Here's some example data (generated using the function [here](http://lastresortsoftware.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/fitting-ellipse-to-point-data.html))

```
X_df <-
structure(list(x = c(550.685479223573, 411.808342674744, 125.337513241526, 
-46.6813176776531, 54.1090479024869, 335.045593380922, 538.806846993829, 
476.123346783785, 207.359201714354, -23.3704356149293, -1.06902389582398, 
252.471032092766, 502.461757269191, 522.09464005165, 290.954504794153, 
22.4116013413886, -37.4399705577234, 166.122770874069, 446.874779008936, 
547.271442128866, 372.271299246978, 84.7905677157295, -50.074206596271, 
90.757431249567, 378.201298931732, 547.145608993239, 443.947162007208, 
161.476775837252, -38.5517112166543, 25.2627436553199, 296.503160027896, 
524.775126009974, 500.784559912938, 245.712512645379, -4.31860487373257, 
-21.9661658669887, 211.218663607589, 479.198761786515, 535.314989389215, 
330.010941011427, 50.0215808044216, -46.3823119064223, 130.383487121344, 
416.170638042649, 549.268852072098, 407.813005658263, 119.940919946473, 
-46.978590114418, 57.7409750579334, 340.505587064792, 539.650771180236, 
472.254339573695, 201.890629521184, -25.163386210777, 1.25193046435474, 
256.776302252232, 506.305676724803, 520.004964534048, 284.257495593069, 
18.8183745840118, -35.9075114459174, 172.662124500953, 452.343060560759, 
546.468842888411, 367.193523099128, 81.9151159445705, -49.726312730029, 
95.1883131124973, 382.503271032958, 548.377552998115, 439.474201456606, 
157.248088356873, -39.8634174011649, 28.665422852919, 301.243788141946, 
526.815879166266, 497.683488701185, 240.939374274905, -7.78381612220116, 
-19.3411744866129, 217.640180353188, 483.134755325255, 534.947529479343, 
324.801587123232, 45.3957868762181, -45.0069945691924, 134.781896592204, 
420.833721926428, 550.278658272823, 403.464000037755, 116.273973349216, 
-48.5483252399878, 62.3918399072614, 345.924165684106, 540.282415561272, 
468.621672005007, 195.304995872248, -28.2738679786754, 4.25351768918281, 
262.272866287766, 509.296144374104), y = c(150.522375543584, 
317.792592638159, 332.783726315973, 177.890614907595, -1.30774215535761, 
-41.9959828735621, 94.0557252742373, 281.491416261009, 347.931229803675, 
232.411150772918, 41.2498141860971, -50.240758928064, 42.4333078345691, 
233.202857825371, 347.930304275537, 279.801242902484, 93.7702821671593, 
-42.9605564915062, -0.128821245055916, 179.228629398932, 331.853832274807, 
317.39347890031, 147.731418574477, -19.2449921421865, -31.3298018420377, 
123.222814177221, 301.499351173211, 340.662811705721, 204.270915882133, 
17.5570334546183, -47.8527634953491, 69.1925023774197, 260.846781070028, 
350.702299892942, 255.267980339802, 64.3048063206447, -47.7550214881633, 
21.0575085383169, 209.247480999408, 342.716023607699, 298.578792586917, 
118.053124236616, -33.3190320226709, -16.5618829502486, 154.097078032767, 
319.940208485997, 330.141085013461, 175.063055837321, -4.17911647131882, 
-40.77087978947, 96.7492568480405, 284.629419943293, 347.18869555741, 
228.951107374031, 37.6230640656836, -49.9549156886126, 45.2896584936418, 
236.96620488459, 349.2183672397, 277.259838492706, 88.5019845874813, 
-43.1419505604449, 1.98249146234145, 183.766146834555, 334.721418603224, 
314.869389642466, 144.917094343997, -21.0615467657252, -29.137753346726, 
126.928148173889, 305.196445845808, 339.338402720207, 201.609402013064, 
15.0779976117978, -47.1046400880924, 71.7191693530443, 263.543031729657, 
350.145628648054, 252.792513384296, 61.2531942049295, -49.0697852698499, 
24.2068045114243, 212.793083656477, 343.533262533366, 295.969945687212, 
115.135250419503, -34.4145910896749, -14.7817206225652, 156.282366465729, 
322.116360452784, 328.626788731125, 171.323808201914, -6.54021515590322, 
-40.1360134761796, 101.492490333309, 286.854230399582, 347.010792855229, 
226.829162028581, 35.3880363162166, -50.8418314561365, 48.893760376765
)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -101L), class = "data.frame")
```

Plot the ellipse, this resembles my actual data:

```
ggplot(X_df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

I want to apply a function to the xy coords to rotate the ellipse around its long axis, moving the top of the ellipse towards me, and the bottom of the ellipse away from me, to get something like this (with equal dimension along the x-axis as the ellipse above, but different dimension along the y-axis):

[image]

I want to rotate my data like this ellipse is rotated to produce the circle, where I see the maximum distance between the top and bottom of the shape (ie. the longest possible axis perpendicular to the long axis), as the shape rotates around it long axis.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this mean that even though the ellipse "looks" two dimensional, it's "really" a circle that's been rotated about an axis through it's center and parallel to the x-axis?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to do what you ask, but if you merely want to transform the coordinates to get a circle, you could do this instead of `coord_equal`: `coord_fixed(ratio=with(X_df, diff(range(x))/diff(range(y))))`

Comment: Or you could apply the same change to the data itself: `X_df$ynew = diff(range(X_df$x))/diff(range(X_df$y)) * X_df$y`. Then `ggplot(X_df, aes(x, ynew)) +
    geom_point() +
    coord_equal()`.

Comment: I think the version suggested by @eipi10 works, but will also translate the vertical position of the circle unless the y coordinates are symmetrical about the x axis.  More generally, your problem is not precisely defined: it depends whether you want the circle to be translated (moved), or if it should have same center as the ellipse.  It's also ambiguous whether to stretch the x or y coordinates (y seems more likely, but good to be specific).  If you can update question on whether the center needs to remain fixed, and which coordinates to stretch, then an answer should should follow shortly.

Comment: Ah, good point @dww. To keep the center fixed, you'd need to subtract `(diff(range(X_df$x))/diff(range(X_df$y)) - 1) * mean(X_df$y)` from `ynew`, (where I've assumed `mean(X_df$y)` is the y coordinate of the center, which is close to true if the data are evenly distributed around the circle/ellipse, but will not be true in general.

Comment: If you liked this question, you'll love this follow-up (with animated gif!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200885/rotate-plotted-points-to-re-project-relative-to-another-set-of-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're saying is that if I viewed the "circle" edge on from, say, x=-1000, y=0, I would see a line rotated counterclockwise (out of the xy-plane) away from the y axis. The goal is to rotate the circle back to the y-axis.

The angle of rotation is `acos(1/ratio)` (0.839 radians or 48.06 degrees in this case) where `ratio` is `diff(range(X_df$x))/diff(range(X_df$y))` (assuming the axis of rotation is in the xy-plane and parallel to the x-axis and your data includes points on the x axis on both sides of the circle).

To, in effect, rotate the circle back to the xy-plane, you could just multiply the y points by `ratio` and then, to maintain the same center, subtract `(ratio - 1) * mean(X_df$y)` (where I've assumed the data points are evenly distributed about the circle).

In other words (or in code, actually):

```
ratio = diff(range(X_df$x))/diff(range(X_df$y))
X_df$ynew = ratio * X_df$y - (ratio - 1) * mean(X_df$y)

ggplot(X_df, aes(x, ynew)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_equal()
```

Compare original to "rotated":

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much, looks very straightforward. I see in my actual use-case that I need to rotate my shapes on two axes. I'll post another question, and link to it here. Seems like you really know what you're doing with this kind of manipulation and could easily solve the problem of two axes.

Comment: Here is my question that is closer to my actual use-case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200885/rotate-plotted-points-to-re-project-relative-to-another-set-of-points