# Rotate plotted points to re-project relative to another set of points

Tags: r, trigonometry

I have a data frame of points that plot outlines of two polygons, one at right angles to the other, like so:

[image]

Here are the data that make that plot:

```
    outlines <-
    structure(list(sample_ids = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "MA15B1-1-5-C21"), 
    pseudolandmark = structure(1:205, .Label = c("C000-000", 
    "C000-001", "C000-002", "C000-003", "C000-004", "C000-005", 
    "C000-006", "C000-007", "C000-008", "C000-009", "C000-010", 
    "C000-011", "C000-012", "C000-013", "C000-014", "C000-015", 
    "C000-016", "C000-017", "C000-018", "C000-019", "C000-020", 
    "C000-021", "C000-022", "C000-023", "C000-024", "C000-025", 
    "C000-026", "C000-027", "C000-028", "C000-029", "C000-030", 
    "C000-031", "C000-032", "C000-033", "C000-034", "C000-035", 
    "C000-036", "C000-037", "C000-038", "C000-039", "C000-040", 
    "C001-000", "C001-001", "C001-002", "C001-003", "C001-004", 
    "C001-005", "C001-006", "C001-007", "C001-008", "C001-009", 
    "C001-010", "C001-011", "C001-012", "C001-013", "C001-014", 
    "C001-015", "C001-016", "C001-017", "C001-018", "C001-019", 
    "C001-020", "C001-021", "C001-022", "C001-023", "C001-024", 
    "C001-025", "C001-026", "C001-027", "C001-028", "C001-029", 
    "C001-030", "C001-031", "C001-032", "C001-033", "C001-034", 
    "C001-035", "C001-036", "C001-037", "C001-038", "C001-039", 
    "C001-040", "C002-000", "C002-001", "C002-002", "C002-003", 
    "C002-004", "C002-005", "C002-006", "C002-007", "C002-008", 
    "C002-009", "C002-010", "C002-011", "C002-012", "C002-013", 
    "C002-014", "C002-015", "C002-016", "C002-017", "C002-018", 
    "C002-019", "C002-020", "C002-021", "C002-022", "C002-023", 
    "C002-024", "C002-025", "C002-026", "C002-027", "C002-028", 
    "C002-029", "C002-030", "C002-031", "C002-032", "C002-033", 
    "C002-034", "C002-035", "C002-036", "C002-037", "C002-038", 
    "C002-039", "C002-040", "C003-000", "C003-001", "C003-002", 
    "C003-003", "C003-004", "C003-005", "C003-006", "C003-007", 
    "C003-008", "C003-009", "C003-010", "C003-011", "C003-012", 
    "C003-013", "C003-014", "C003-015", "C003-016", "C003-017", 
    "C003-018", "C003-019", "C003-020", "C003-021", "C003-022", 
    "C003-023", "C003-024", "C003-025", "C003-026", "C003-027", 
    "C003-028", "C003-029", "C003-030", "C003-031", "C003-032", 
    "C003-033", "C003-034", "C003-035", "C003-036", "C003-037", 
    "C003-038", "C003-039", "C003-040", "C004-000", "C004-001", 
    "C004-002", "C004-003", "C004-004", "C004-005", "C004-006", 
    "C004-007", "C004-008", "C004-009", "C004-010", "C004-011", 
    "C004-012", "C004-013", "C004-014", "C004-015", "C004-016", 
    "C004-017", "C004-018", "C004-019", "C004-020", "C004-021", 
    "C004-022", "C004-023", "C004-024", "C004-025", "C004-026", 
    "C004-027", "C004-028", "C004-029", "C004-030", "C004-031", 
    "C004-032", "C004-033", "C004-034", "C004-035", "C004-036", 
    "C004-037", "C004-038", "C004-039", "C004-040"), class = "factor"), 
    x = c(12.016122, 11.541907, 11.038835, 10.502722, 9.9116697, 
    9.2927132, 8.7031393, 8.2882128, 7.7682838, 7.4592881, 7.1727204, 
    6.882329, 6.5730295, 6.2629328, 5.974225, 5.6768575, 5.3772326, 
    5.0374117, 4.6981254, 4.3568606, 4.0674963, 3.7128081, 3.3609159, 
    3.0815868, 2.6982265, 2.3401613, 2.1256597, 1.6268489, 1.1917412, 
    1.0033085, 0.88194823, 0.7922346, 0.65476406, 0.388096, 0.21852912, 
    -0.060025979, -0.25463527, -0.43339792, -0.67199445, -0.74821764, 
    -1.0261612, -1.0261612, -0.92627585, -0.61627114, -0.26953429, 
    0.025590658, 0.22602104, 0.49005115, 0.77080095, 1.0086451, 
    1.2377149, 1.486245, 1.7201869, 1.973778, 2.2724597, 2.5824413, 
    2.964093, 3.2498548, 3.5646105, 3.9470801, 4.323751, 4.7156439, 
    5.1217055, 5.4455066, 5.72192, 6.0532079, 6.4232531, 6.8666763, 
    7.2917495, 7.7359419, 8.1826134, 8.6566973, 9.1541157, 9.6898823, 
    10.248864, 10.848221, 11.471651, 12.131388, 12.808134, 13.460155, 
    14.156513, 14.82901, 14.82901, 15.673672, 16.729141, 17.791584, 
    18.740608, 19.599586, 20.401081, 21.159971, 21.838057, 22.454126, 
    22.9597, 23.358027, 23.555031, 23.598192, 23.432957, 23.228603, 
    23.358398, 23.26931, 23.070007, 22.818201, 22.594666, 22.324627, 
    22.001938, 21.619722, 21.251596, 20.906891, 20.514589, 20.084562, 
    19.653286, 19.200079, 18.76742, 18.308954, 17.817726, 17.29768, 
    16.733225, 16.100943, 15.422856, 14.715117, 13.926449, 13.005936, 
    12.016122, -13.766603, -13.935621, -14.166668, -14.608814, 
    -14.919644, -14.839896, -12.870626, -10.359905, -5.3109751, 
    1.5327182, 5.367815, 8.0128088, 10.083024, 11.875553, 13.479352, 
    15.080202, 16.57955, 18.080011, 19.587444, 21.106117, 22.594666, 
    24.057869, 25.619652, 27.149252, 28.715357, 30.36421, 32.024361, 
    33.747543, 35.465405, 37.282791, 39.083374, 40.917885, 42.782429, 
    44.547249, 46.517342, 48.3228, 50.025127, 51.226521, 51.79425, 
    51.81292, 51.350864, 51.350864, 50.712288, 49.727493, 48.188499, 
    46.295891, 43.634846, 39.408772, 34.239418, 29.100199, 24.750076, 
    20.78437, 17.448862, 14.623836, 12.187436, 10.035782, 8.1002054, 
    6.2869821, 4.5976009, 2.9719067, 1.4258807, -0.022152033, 
    -1.4664655, -2.8909578, -4.3156242, -5.6212177, -7.0099473, 
    -8.3390236, -9.6840572, -10.756982, -11.072048, -11.078612, 
    -11.288648, -11.518431, -11.715311, -12.164374, -12.689521, 
    -12.874741, -12.984236, -13.186749, -13.325057, -13.766603
    ), y = c(-29.035833, -29.341286, -29.524191, -29.617352, 
    -29.582525, -29.559042, -29.727335, -30.435453, -30.877647, 
    -31.823519, -32.774418, -33.682446, -34.534527, -35.375267, 
    -36.243355, -37.097054, -37.951897, -38.769203, -39.605328, 
    -40.459553, -41.383324, -42.267879, -43.180614, -44.17408, 
    -45.114273, -46.101246, -47.206028, -48.160709, -49.188194, 
    -50.379581, -51.624416, -52.90226, -54.175545, -55.411297, 
    -56.715446, -57.996536, -59.338886, -60.712456, -62.08672, 
    -63.551258, -64.960548, -64.960548, -66.095848, -67.283829, 
    -68.451477, -69.582626, -70.686172, -71.78344, -72.867096, 
    -73.942451, -75.013359, -76.076859, -77.141106, -78.198891, 
    -79.238411, -80.269211, -81.259293, -82.296562, -83.31955, 
    -84.296532, -85.274673, -86.239151, -87.189964, -88.227707, 
    -89.338547, -90.414749, -91.467842, -92.440331, -93.458946, 
    -94.472794, -95.514389, -96.540703, -97.558075, -98.525612, 
    -99.472214, -100.33396, -101.13947, -101.80611, -102.3606, 
    -103.02946, -103.25335, -103.3634, -103.3634, -103.23396, 
    -101.97776, -99.767479, -97.053017, -94.317451, -91.671646, 
    -89.110168, -86.560768, -84.055862, -81.558327, -79.093147, 
    -76.637794, -74.252075, -71.948479, -69.772507, -67.696037, 
    -65.677223, -63.73584, -61.868732, -60.046165, -58.283794, 
    -56.586216, -54.961853, -53.364918, -51.774773, -50.241127, 
    -48.760128, -47.291809, -45.853298, -44.371704, -42.896107, 
    -41.429131, -39.946079, -38.466869, -37.086483, -35.756569, 
    -34.21907, -32.492996, -30.540468, -29.035833, -64.279663, 
    -64.431847, -64.572395, -64.716911, -64.756622, -64.598656, 
    -63.945881, -63.02924, -61.699482, -60.840389, -60.469181, 
    -60.270256, -60.174934, -60.11552, -60.097019, -60.055656, 
    -60.050323, -60.042873, -60.036118, -60.031452, -60.046165, 
    -60.07896, -60.085617, -60.114563, -60.141598, -60.151379, 
    -60.169483, -60.178539, -60.202236, -60.205612, -60.228111, 
    -60.25304, -60.282089, -60.357517, -60.381199, -60.472359, 
    -60.610611, -60.919216, -61.434845, -62.125805, -62.965706, 
    -62.965706, -62.721577, -62.7005, -62.964176, -63.475807, 
    -64.327568, -65.531982, -66.759201, -67.726349, -68.583122, 
    -69.032181, -69.287346, -69.39106, -69.402908, -69.362747, 
    -69.289207, -69.224113, -69.148056, -69.087257, -69.023453, 
    -68.941978, -68.890068, -68.853645, -68.838669, -68.784042, 
    -68.784935, -68.770088, -68.771759, -68.66272, -68.247192, 
    -67.730736, -67.32209, -66.940979, -66.564262, -66.290703, 
    -66.0466, -65.689575, -65.31218, -64.962807, -64.588394, 
    -64.279663), z = c(-11.640717, -12.212139, -12.790169, -13.404076, 
    -14.090126, -14.849237, -15.624723, -16.223763, -16.94533, 
    -17.385506, -17.770006, -18.141287, -18.529652, -18.912949, 
    -19.258121, -19.616081, -19.978848, -20.412086, -20.848568, 
    -21.292707, -21.653788, -22.129126, -22.603168, -22.961033, 
    -23.492054, -23.98238, -24.24798, -24.95643, -25.557547, 
    -25.78834, -25.931046, -26.042557, -26.233328, -26.602404, 
    -26.848875, -27.232805, -27.515375, -27.78298, -28.115961, 
    -28.284237, -28.652328, -28.652328, -28.618475, -28.382553, 
    -28.104822, -27.870857, -27.725304, -27.513765, -27.281839, 
    -27.089834, -26.904253, -26.696451, -26.501493, -26.284134, 
    -26.017385, -25.736273, -25.376564, -25.116371, -24.823265, 
    -24.455084, -24.090719, -23.707504, -23.306538, -22.99367, 
    -22.731548, -22.407658, -22.039309, -21.587664, -21.154367, 
    -20.697742, -20.23628, -19.742008, -19.219334, -18.651316, 
    -18.054804, -17.410599, -16.73704, -16.020861, -15.284132, 
    -14.572757, -13.813521, -13.082184, -13.082184, -11.836174, 
    -10.371157, -8.9146891, -7.5984855, -6.3909879, -5.2539153, 
    -4.1701441, -3.1843925, -2.2747555, -1.4981418, -0.85124946, 
    -0.44579506, -0.22767115, -0.26378655, -0.35496628, -0.052757025, 
    -0.018972158, -0.12546009, -0.30359784, -0.45423844, -0.66924334, 
    -0.9572376, -1.3283906, -1.6891971, -2.0254967, -2.4296074, 
    -2.8898013, -3.3561993, -3.856319, -4.3255644, -4.8272915, 
    -5.3697472, -5.9422278, -6.5665784, -7.2926774, -8.0842562, 
    -8.8555298, -9.6650724, -10.555345, -11.640717, -2.7672737, 
    -2.1903069, -1.2737914, 0.16836274, 2.4672432, 5.9690843, 
    10.210753, 15.91739, 19.899754, 14.792585, 11.754315, 9.7791786, 
    8.1368742, 6.8233938, 5.5829773, 4.618804, 3.5732141, 2.5846314, 
    1.6089522, 0.62011236, -0.45423844, -1.6118737, -2.7228773, 
    -3.9464815, -5.2166457, -6.505352, -7.8890376, -9.3358879, 
    -10.906958, -12.543717, -14.332139, -16.252239, -18.320354, 
    -20.591578, -22.985493, -25.616528, -28.454372, -31.466019, 
    -34.491833, -37.347115, -39.844269, -39.844269, -40.963715, 
    -42.466965, -44.281563, -46.622925, -49.180168, -50.47818, 
    -50.001698, -48.150879, -47.208149, -44.766876, -42.444233, 
    -40.224083, -38.183632, -36.332493, -34.635815, -33.141499, 
    -31.745464, -30.478825, -29.272392, -28.079586, -26.989384, 
    -25.958443, -24.988785, -23.958261, -23.041853, -22.102564, 
    -21.195795, -20.102522, -18.509001, -16.776804, -15.243351, 
    -13.770063, -12.316394, -11.027509, -9.7839518, -8.3760729, 
    -6.9421391, -5.5482216, -4.1175952, -2.7672737)), .Names = c("sample_ids", 
"pseudolandmark", "x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -205L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code for the 3d plot above:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(outlines, x = x, y = y, z = z, 
        text = pseudolandmark,
        type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", 
        marker = list(size = 2))
```

Now I convert to a dataframe, and plot in 2d

```
outlines_df <-  data.frame(pseudolandmark = outlines[,2], 
                           x = as.numeric(outlines[,3]), 
                           y = as.numeric(outlines[,4]),
                           z = as.numeric(outlines[,5]))

ggplot(outlines_df, aes(x, z)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

This is ideal for one of the outlines, it's like the view is directly perpendicular to the plan of the outline. This seems like a very accurate representation of that particular cross-section of the object.

But I'm stuck at rotating the dataset to project the second outline into 2d so that I see the outline as 'flat', ie. at 90 degrees to the first outline. If I simply use x and y coords instead of x and z (as above), the result is slightly skewed (I want to see the horizontal outline as a single line, as if I am looking at its thin edge):

[image]

Here's the second outline by itself

```
second_outline <- outlines_df[1:123, ]

ggplot(second_outline, aes(x, z)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

The result is as if I have a peculiar slice through the 3d space. What I want to get is a 2d projection that looks like this:

[image]

This view shows the outline 'flat', and perpendicular to the other outline.

I [first thought that a simple rotation would solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193380/rotate-plotted-points-of-an-ellipse-to-give-a-circle), but that's not quite right:

```
ratio = diff(range(first_outline$x))/diff(range(first_outline$z))
first_outline$znew = ratio * first_outline$z - (ratio - 1) * mean(first_outline$z)

ggplot(first_outline, aes(x, znew)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image: enter code here]

Or if I apply this rotation to the y-axis, the result is not right:

```
ratio = diff(range(first_outline$x))/diff(range(first_outline$y))
first_outline$ynew = ratio * first_outline$y - (ratio - 1) * mean(first_outline$y)

ggplot(first_outline, aes(x, ynew)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

How can I rotate the data to get the projection that I want for the second outline?

I see in the literature about tensors and inertia tensors, but I'm not sure how to get started with those.

Comment: I think what you want is principle component analysis. Working out the precise details for a generalised version of this problem will take a little more time than I have right now. But since you say the planes of the 2 polygons intersect at 90 degrees we can simplify.  i think it will be somethin like this...The x axis of your 2d plot should be the first principle component of the first polygon, and the y axis will be the 1st pc of the second polygon rotated through 90 degrees.

Comment: On looking more closely, I notice that your data frame does not distinguish which points lie in which polygon. To use the above method, you would need to 1st separate them out. Once again, pca is your friend, to find out which points lie outside of the plane formed by the 2 principle components corresponding to the major and minor axes of one of the polygons. However, once again drawing on the fact that the polygons intersect at 90 deg we can simplify even more (running out of characters so on to next comment...)

Comment: So, simplest method I can think of requires a little trial and error. The x axis is 1st pc. Then try using 2nd pc as y axis. Either this is what you want, or (depending on how the points are spread) it may look like 2 intersecting lines in an X, as you view the object orthogonal to both planes. If what you see is an x, then plot 3rd pc as the y axis. This should hopefully be the correct view.  If you are still stuck on this a couple of days from now, I might find time to tinker over the weekend to get you a full answer, but hopefully these suggestions will work out.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion, sounds very promising, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from [dww's helpful comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200885/rotate-plotted-points-to-re-project-relative-to-another-set-of-points?noredirect=1#comment61947715_37200885), here's a PCA of the coordinates:

```
# compute PCA...
first_outline_pca <- prcomp(first_outline[ , c('x', 'y', 'z')], 
                            scores = TRUE, 
                            cor = FALSE)
# extract PCs...
compscores <- data.frame(first_outline_pca$x[ ,1:3])

# plot to see what the result is...
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = compscores, aes(PC1, PC2), colour = "red") +
  geom_point(data = compscores, aes(mean(PC1), mean(PC2)), colour = "green") +
  geom_point(data = first_outline, aes(x, z), colour = "blue") +
  geom_point(data = first_outline, aes(mean(x), mean(z)), colour = "green") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The blue is the original raw coords, and the red is the PCA-transformed coords. And that red outline looks pretty much exactly like what I was expecting, fantastic!